# How can I get out of this infinite loop?

Tags: recursion, linked-list, infinite-loop

I am writing a recursive function to find the index of a node in a linked list. It looks like this:

```
function indexAt(node, collection, linkedList) {
 let index = 0;
 if (node === nodeAt(index, linkedList,collection)) {
  return index
 } else { 
  index ++
  return indexAt(node, collection, linkedList)
 }
}
```

It calls on the nodeAt function, which looks like this:

```
function nodeAt(index, linkedList, collection) {
  let node = collection[linkedList];
  for (let i=0; i < index; i++) {
    node = next(node, collection)
  }
  return node
 }
```

This works fine when the index is 0, but when it is anything else, it increments the index, then sets it back to 0, entering an infinite loop. How can I fix this without fundamentally altering the code?

Comment: *"How can I fix this without fundamentally altering the code"?* You can't. This code is fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Well at the start of the function you reset the index to 0. So every time it recurs, it resets the index, thus causing your infinite loop.

An easy fix is to declare the index variable outside the function. That will ensure it's not reset every time the function recurs.

A better fix would be to pass the index as an argument to the function so that it will always keep track of its own index.

Comment: Thanks! Declaring it outside the function works. I agree, adding it as an argument would be a better solution, but I didnt write the tests and they call for three arguments. Theres Probably a better way to do this but recursion was all that came to mind

Comment: @adamtropp if you could mark it as correct if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Just make a helper that holds the extra variable:

```
function indexAt(node, collection, linkedList) {
    function indexAt(index, node, collection, linkedList) {
        if (node === nodeAt(index, linkedList, collection)) {
            return index
        } else {
            return indexAt(index + 1, node, collection, linkedList)
        }
    }
    return indexAt(0, node, collection, linkedList);
}
```

Now you count from 0...n and make `nodeAt` start at the beginning each time making this O(n^2). A much better way would be that the helper has the current node, initialized at `collection[linkedList]` and stepping with `next(currentNode)` and `index + 1` until `node === currentNode`. That would be a O(n) solution. `indexAt` doesn't really need to be recursive unless it is a requirement.